# How to replace pandas dataframe values based on lookup values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe with numerical values structured like this:

```
>>> df1
   A  B  C
0  2  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  1
```

I need to replace all of the the above cell values with a 'description' that maps to the field name and cell value as referenced in another dataframe structured like this:

```
>>> df2
  field_name  code description
0          A     1          NO
1          A     2         YES
2          A     3       MAYBE
3          B     1           x
4          B     2           y
5          B     3           z
6          C     1        GOOD
7          C     2         BAD
8          C     3        FINE
```

The desired output would be like:

```
>>> df3
     A  B     C
0  YES  x   BAD
1   NO  y  FINE
2  YES  z  GOOD
```

I could figure out a way to do this on a small scale using something like .map or .replace - however the actual datasets contain thousands of records with hundreds of different combinations to replace. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, you posted two times the same image!

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe, we can copy it with `pd.read_clipboard`. Also I think you could show the expected output ( for example dataframe)

Comment: What is the expected dataframe?

Comment: Sorry all - i've now pasted the dataframes in and included the desired output - thanks!

Comment: Please provide the data in a convenient format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df1.replace(df2.pivot(columns='field_name', index='code', values='description')
                     .to_dict())
```

maybe you need select columns previously:

```
df1[cols] = df1[cols].replace(df2.pivot(columns='field_name',
                                        index='code', values='description')
                                 .to_dict())
```

**Output**

```
print(df1)
     A  B     C
0  YES  x   BAD
1   NO  y  FINE
2  YES  z  GOOD
```

Comment: Ah looks like this might've worked perfectly! Will try it on the full dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can unstack `df1`, merge with `df2` and `pivot` the result:

```
df3 = df1.stack().reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_1': 'field_name', 0: 'code'}).merge(
        df2, 'left', on=['field_name', 'code']).pivot(
            index='level_0', columns='field_name',
            values='description').rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: isn't this clearly slower? I think there are too many changes in the format